# Let $G=(V,E)$ be a connected graph with $|E|=17$ and for all vertices $\deg(v)>3$. What is the maximum value of $|V|$?

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a connected graph with $|E|=17$ and for all vertices $\deg(v)>3$. What is the maximum value of $|V|$? (What is the maximum possible number of vertices?)

Comment: What is max v??

Comment: @Graphth: I interpret ing to be asking what the maximum possible number of vertices is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: Suppose that $V=\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$. Then $$\sum_{k=1}^n\deg(v_k)=34\;;\tag{1}$$ why?

If $\deg(v_k)\ge 4$ for $k=1,\dots,n$, then $$\sum_{k=1}^n\deg(v_k)\ge\sum_{k=1}^n4\;.\tag{2}$$ Now combine $(1)$ and $(2)$.

Comment: maximum possible number of vertices is = 8?

Comment: @ing: Yes: you have $34\ge 4n$, so $n\le\frac{34}4$, and since $n$ must be an integer, $n\le 8$.

Answer (score 0):

There are $24$ non-isomorphic $8$-vertex $17$-edge connected graphs with minimum degree $\geq 4$.  They can be generated using `geng` which comes with [nauty](http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/nauty/) using the command:

```
geng 8 17:17 -d4 -c
```

I wrote a script to display the output.  Here's the result:

[image: The $24$ non-isomorphic $8$-vertex $17$-edge connected graphs with minimum degree $\geq 4$.]

The first one is $K_{4,4}$ with an additional edge.

By the way, if we attempt

```
geng 9 17:17 -d4 -c
```

we receive the response:

```
>E geng: impossible mine,maxe,mindeg,maxdeg values
```

which gives a computer verification that $8$ is indeed the maximum value.