# If $G =(V, E)$ is a connected graph with $E = 17,\deg(v)\ge3\quad\forall v\in V$, what is the maximum value for $V$?

Tags: graph-theory

> If $G =(V, E)$ is a connected graph with $E = 17,\deg(v)\ge3\quad\forall v\in V$, what is the maximum value for $V$?

Could somebody please explain the answer with a detailed solution.
I need to comprehend the logic behind the answer. This question is from Discrete and combinatorial mathematics by Ralph Grimaldi. And the answer to the question is 11. I would like to understand the reasoning, the logic and a way of arriving at the answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Let $G=(V,E)$ be a connected graph with $|E|=17$ and for all vertices $\deg(v)&gt;3$. What is the maximum value of $|V|$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217390/let-g-v-e-be-a-connected-graph-with-e-17-and-for-all-vertices-degv3)

Comment: Well, clearly $|V| \leq |E|/3<6$. Can it be done with 5 vertices?

Comment: @StubbornAtom: Not quite a duplicate: in the earlier question $\deg v\ge 4$ for all $v$. Of course the basic idea is exactly the same, and Rahul should definitely look at that question and answer.

Comment: So this is what I think: As per degree sum formula, the sum of all degrees of vertices in this case would be 2 X 17 = 34. Now I must think of a valid solution to find the maximum number of vertices. And for that, degree of most of the vertices should be 3.
 From here on, I need some help in arriving at the solution.

Comment: Your description in your comment does not seem to agree with your question. Please clean up the notation in your question.

Comment: @StubbornAtom & Brian M.Scott: Thanks for the link. I read the answer. And just to let you know, this question is from the Discrete Maths book by Ralph Grimaldi. And the answer to this question is 11. But I want to understand how do I derive at the answer.

Comment: @Ian: This is exactly the question given in the book, Discrete and combinatorial mathematics by Ralph Grimaldi

Comment: Oh, yes, now I see what you were doing. So yes, since the degree sum is 34 and each vertex has degree at least 3, there can be at most $34/3$ vertices; but $11<34/3<12$. So the best possible number based on this consideration is $11$, and the only question is whether this can actually be done with $11$ vertices. For that I think you would want an explicit construction. Perhaps you can start with a linear graph and just insert edges until you get to the desired target?

Comment: @Ian: Exactly my thoughts. I too am confused with you last statement. How do I even construct it. Grimaldi has few more questions where he just draws the graph. But I think it will take a long time to arrive at a suitable graph. I was just thinking if there is an easier way out

Comment: Well, the linear graph on $11$ vertices has $10$ edges, and each vertex except for the last two has degree $2$ (those two have degree $1$). (It's also connected, so we can forget about the connectivity requirement now.) Since those two are lower, let's throw in another edge between them, resulting in the cyclic graph on $11$ vertices. So now we have 11 edges and each vertex has degree 2. How can you throw in six more edges to raise the degrees of all $11$ vertices to be at least $3$? (Hint: note that the degree sum is $34$, so one vertex will have degree 4 and the rest will have degree 3.)